# Modify L-shaped section of matrix in R

Tags: r

I have a square matrix, and I wish to do something to all values in some of the outer rows and columns, e.g. multiply everything in rows and cols `g:j` in `abmat` by 10:

```r
abmat <-matrix(
  data = rpois(n = 10*10, lambda = 1),
  nrow = 10,
  dimnames = list(letters[1:10], letters[1:10])
)

abmat
#>   a b c d e f g h i j
#> a 0 2 2 1 0 0 0 1 1 2
#> b 2 1 2 2 0 1 0 0 1 1
#> c 1 0 1 2 0 2 2 1 1 0
#> d 0 2 0 0 1 3 1 1 3 1
#> e 0 0 1 1 3 2 1 1 1 0
#> f 1 1 1 1 2 0 2 1 0 1
#> g 0 0 2 1 0 0 0 0 1 3
#> h 0 2 2 0 1 0 2 1 1 1
#> i 1 1 0 2 0 0 2 1 0 1
#> j 0 0 2 0 0 0 1 1 2 1
```

Seems like I might be able to by exclusion, but actually this excludes everything in the row / column specified, so only gives the bottom corner, not the backwards L section I want:

```r
abmat[-1:-6, -1:-6]*10
#>    g  h  i  j
#> g  0  0 10 30
#> h 20 10 10 10
#> i 20 10  0 10
#> j 10 10 20 10
#no
```

I can by breaking it up and operating on two different shaped sections to create the backwards-L:

```r
abmat2 <- abmat
abmat2[7:10,] <- abmat[7:10,]*10
abmat2[1:6, 7:10] <- abmat[1:6, 7:10]*10

abmat2
#>    a  b  c  d  e f  g  h  i  j
#> a  0  2  2  1  0 0  0 10 10 20
#> b  2  1  2  2  0 1  0  0 10 10
#> c  1  0  1  2  0 2 20 10 10  0
#> d  0  2  0  0  1 3 10 10 30 10
#> e  0  0  1  1  3 2 10 10 10  0
#> f  1  1  1  1  2 0 20 10  0 10
#> g  0  0 20 10  0 0  0  0 10 30
#> h  0 20 20  0 10 0 20 10 10 10
#> i 10 10  0 20  0 0 20 10  0 10
#> j  0  0 20  0  0 0 10 10 20 10
#yes
```

Yay, works, but is a bit fiddly - is there a more straightforward way to do this?

<sup>Created on 2022-11-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Here's one generic implementation for square n*n matrix `x` where you want to multiply all elements in either rows `r:n` or columns `r:n` by a scalar value `m`

Although I'm not sure if it's any less fiddly than your approach

```
myfun <- function(x, r, m) {
    vec <- c(rep(1, r-1), rep(2, nrow(x)-r+1)) #indicate rows/cols to modify
    tf <- tcrossprod(vec) > 1                  #matrix of trues/falses
    x*(!tf) + x*tf*m                           #combine original and modified elements
}

myfun(x=abmat, r=7, m=10)

#    a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j
# a  0  0  2  3  2  0 10  0  0 20
# b  1  2  1  0  0  1 10  0  0 10
# c  1  2  0  2  0  2 20 10 10 10
# d  2  1  0  1  1  0  0 10 20  0
# e  1  0  2  0  4  0 10  0  0 20
# f  2  0  2  1  0  2 20  0  0  0
# g  0 10 10 10  0 10 10 10  0 20
# h  0  0 10  0 30  0  0 10 20  0
# i 20  0 10 50  0  0 20 10  0 10
# j  0  0 10 20 10 20 20 20 10 20
```

Comment: a slightly modified version: `abmat* (1 - tcrossprod(rep(c(1, 0), c(6, 4)))) * 10` :)